# Can't use .insertAdjacentHTML within a nested for loop

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I can't use .insertAdjacentHTML because I just don't get how.

```js
for(let i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
        for(let j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            document.querySelector(".matrice-" + p).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input class="l' + i + 'c' + 'j" size="3" maxlength="4" inputmode="numeric"></input>')
        }
        document.querySelector(".matrice-" + p).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br/>')
    }
    }
```

I want the input classes to be like l1c1 l1c2 l1c3 and so on but I can't seem to get that j to work as the variable. It is being used as a string so all my classes are l1cj l2cj and so on.

The fact that I have to use so many quotation marks really confuses me.

How should I use it to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got this right you're trying to create a maxtrix of l rows and c columns. Instead of attaching elements (as HTML) to the DOM on each loop iteration (which is costly performance-wise), just push each input into an array. Then you can join that array and use `insertAdjacentHTML` to add the HTML to the page at the end.

Here I've used a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) too so there is less confusion about where the quotes should go. I added a placeholder to the input to show you how the classes look so you don't have to inspect the page.

Hope it helps.

```js
const arr = [];
const m = n = 3;

for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    const input = `
      <input
        class="l${i}c${j}
        size="3"
        maxlength="4"
        inputmode="numeric"
        placeholder="l${i}c${j}"
      />`;
    arr.push(input);
  }
}

const root = document.querySelector('#root')
root.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', arr.join(''));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#root {
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

input {
  -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this? "l${i}c${j}"

Comment: In a template literal variables can be inserted like `${var}`. It means that you don't have to keep quote/unquoting the string to insert them.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for your time. I will try to use it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is wrong. `j` should not be inside the quotes.

```
document.querySelector(".matrice-" + p).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input class="l' + i + 'c' + j + '" size="3" maxlength="4" inputmode="numeric"></input>')
```

The method in the other answer will be more efficient -- every time you call `insertAdjacentHTML()` the browser has to parse the new HTML. Doing it all at once is generally better.